# removing xmlns from xml file

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

Hi I am Appending new Elements into XML file which is creating additional xmlns attribute and cannot be removed. i tried most of the common options

here's my code

This Add's new Entrys to the XML file

```
Private Sub AddNewElement(ByRef FileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo)

        Dim bln As Boolean = False
        Dim XmlDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = Nothing
        Dim OAssemblyInfo As AssemblyInfo = Nothing
        Dim NodeDependentAssembly As System.Xml.XmlNode
        Dim NodeAssemblyIdentity As System.Xml.XmlNode = Nothing
        Dim NodeBindingRedirect As System.Xml.XmlNode = Nothing
        Dim nodelist As System.Xml.XmlNodeList

        Try
            Dim cr As String = Environment.NewLine
            Dim newElement As String = _
           "<dependentAssembly>" & cr & _
           "<assemblyIdentity name=" & """" & "ABCEntities" & """" & " publicKeyToken=" & """" & "21f532fe36bf9cd6" & """" & " culture=" & """" & "neutral" & """" & " />" & cr & _
           "<bindingRedirect oldVersion=" & """" & "1.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" & """" & " newVersion=" & """" & "7.136.13.0" & """" & " />" & cr & _
           "<codeBase version=" & """" & "7.136.13.0" & """" & " href=" & """" & "file:///C:\Program Files\ABC\ABCEntities.dll" & """" & " />" & cr & _
           "</dependentAssembly>" & cr & _
          "<dependentAssembly>" & cr & _
           "<assemblyIdentity name=" & """" & "ABCProcesses" & """" & " publicKeyToken=" & """" & "21f532fe36bf9cd6" & """" & " culture=" & """" & "neutral" & """" & " />" & cr & _
           "<bindingRedirect oldVersion=" & """" & "1.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" & """" & " newVersion=" & """" & "7.136.13.0" & """" & " />" & cr & _
           "<codeBase version=" & """" & "7.136.13.0" & """" & " href=" & """" & "file:///C:\Program Files\ABC\ABCProcesses.dll" & """" & " />" & cr & _
          "</dependentAssembly>" & cr


            ' Load the config file into the XML DOM.
            XmlDoc = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
            XmlDoc.Load(FileInfo.FullName)

            For Each NodeDependentAssembly In XmlDoc.Item("configuration").Item("runtime").Item("assemblyBinding")
                ' Skip any comments.
                If NodeDependentAssembly.Name = "dependentAssembly" Then

                    If NodeDependentAssembly.HasChildNodes = True Then

                        nodelist = NodeDependentAssembly.ChildNodes
                        NodeAssemblyIdentity = nodelist.ItemOf(0)


                        Select Case NodeAssemblyIdentity.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value

                            Case "ABCEntities"
                                bln = True

                            Case "ABCProcesses"
                                bln = True
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            Next



            If bln = False Then

                Dim docFrag As XmlDocumentFragment = XmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment()


                docFrag.InnerXml = newElement
                                    Dim root As XmlNode = XmlDoc.Item("configuration").Item("runtime").Item("assemblyBinding")

                root.AppendChild(docFrag)

                ' Save the Xml.
                XmlDoc.Save(FileInfo.FullName)


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            XmlDoc = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Above code adds uncessary xmlns which cannot be removed ......atleast easily

Here's the code i have tried to remove but not worked so far (its not complete function for simplicity)

```
   ' Load the config file into the XML DOM.
            XmlDoc = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
            XmlDoc.Load(FileInfo.FullName)


            For Each NodeDependentAssembly In XmlDoc.Item("configuration").Item("runtime").Item("assemblyBinding")

                ' Skip any comments.
                If NodeDependentAssembly.Name = "dependentAssembly" Then

                    If NodeDependentAssembly.Attributes.Count > 0 Then
                        NodeDependentAssembly.Attributes.RemoveAll()
                        NodeDependentAssembly.OuterXml.Replace("xmlns", "")
                        NodeDependentAssembly.Attributes.RemoveAll()
                    End If
```

here's the XML config file with two new entrys

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly xmlns=""> -----------remove xmlns from here
               <assemblyIdentity name="ABCEntities" publicKeyToken="21f532fe36bf9cd6" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535 " newVersion="7.136.13.0" />
        <codeBase version="7.136.13.0" href="file:///C:\Program Files\ABC\ABCEntities.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly xmlns=""> -----------remove xmlns from here
        <assemblyIdentity name="ABCProcesses" publicKeyToken="21f532fe36bf9cd6" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535 " newVersion="7.136.13.0" />
        <codeBase version="7.136.13.0" href="file:///C:\Program Files\ABC\ABCProcesses.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML that you're creating in your string literal has no namespace declared on the elements.  The element you're appending it to belongs to a namespace.  The parser is correct in adding `xmlns=""` to the new elements - if it didn't, it would be changing their namespace.

To fix this, add a namespace declaration to the XML elements you're adding, declaring them to be in the same namespace as the document you're adding them to.  Change:

```
<dependentAssembly>
```

to:

```
<dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
```

When you do this, the parser won't need to put an `xmlns` declaration on the elements, because it will see that they already belong to the namespace that the parent element is in.

One other thing:  look up VB.Net's support for [XML literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068%28VS.80%29.aspx#vb9overview_topic6).

Comment: Nope that didn't work ?? it puts <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  instead of just <dependentAssembly>

Comment: In your output, do `assemblyBinding` and its child `dependentAssembly` have exactly the same namespace declaration on them?